# Credit Card Info On Databases

Tags: database

In version 1.4 there were two databases which held stored credit card numbers:

sales_flat_quote_payment     &    sales_orders_entity_varchar

The first one is still there in version 1.9 but not the second.

We like to delete these numbers regularly. Are there any other databases which hold CC numbers in ver 1.9 ?

Answer (score 2):

Two table "sales_flat_quote_payment" and "sales_flat_order_payment" store credit card number based on payment method config. If your payment method hold this following config then credit card information not save into database, so you can control credit card information save from code.

```
protected $_canSaveCc   = false;
```

Note that it is likely a violation of PCI guidelines and generally not a good idea to store this data in your database.